# NSPredicate SUBQUERY for object composed of arrays of other objects

Tags: nspredicate

given that I have an object that has the below data (representated in JSON). I was curious to know if there is a way to write a subquery or use NSPredicate without blocks to directly extract only those subjects that have an test with status of "W" only.

ie get the below from just NSPredicates.

```
NSArray *list = [self.event.subjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(subject *subject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    for (test *test in subject.tests) {
        if ([test.status.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"w"]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}]];



{
"id": 860142,
"subjectList": [
    {
        "id": 12206971,
        "testList": [
            {
                "id": 76904260,
                "status": "W"
            },
            {
                "id": 76904291,
                "status": "L"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "id": 12206971,
        "testList": [
            {
                "id": 76904260,
                "status": "L"
            },
            {
                "id": 76904291,
                "status": "L"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this solution... I think it was just a case of feeling too intimidated by SUBQUERY as the solution just turned out to be so simple.

```
 [self.event.subjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tests, $x, $x.status.lowercaseString == 'w').@count > 0"]];
```